# How to quickly show my text, just want to display it

Tags: variables, autohotkey

check my code, i'm currently using this method, i just want to show my text, but it's taking too long, i want to show it quickly, like ctrl c ctrl v, is it possible? 
What's the better way?
i want to press "sendbigtest" and space and show my big text, thank you..

`:r:]sendbigtest::
Send,
(
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?""Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"`

) 
return

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the text to the clipboard and sending paste.

```
:r:]sendbigtest::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll ; to preserve previous clipboard contents
clipboard =
(
Sed ut perspiciatis . . .
)
Send , ^v
clipboard := ClipSaved ; restore clipboard contents
ClipSaved := "" ; clear in case clipboard was very large
Return
```

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem. We practily did a ctrl+c ctrl+v saving the text. 
Is there other way to be faster? without sending paste...
Is it normal to take a long time using "send' to send text

Comment: AFAIK, there is no faster way. Even when with max. speed settings, it still takes ~4 seconds on my machine. Here is a link for the max. speed settings: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=6413

Answer (score 0):

For only showing the text, (e.g. no copying is required) you can use one of the options below.
One uses the [SplashTextOn/SplashTextOff](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SplashTextOn.htm) commands.

The other one piggybacks on the [Progress](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Progress.htm) command. It uses the special option `zh0` that actually hides the progress bar, but the description text is left - which is what we need.

> To have more control over layout and font name/color/size, use the
>   Progress command with the zh0 option, which omits the bar and displays
>   only text. For example:
>    `Progress, zh0 fs18, Some 18-point text to display.`

Both options use <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close the popup window.

---

**Option using Splash text:**

```
bigtext =
(
Put all your big text here
Put all your big text here
Put all your big text here
)

:r:]sendbigtest::
SplashTextOn , 900, 600, TEST, %bigtext%
return

~esc::SplashTextOff
```

---

**Option using Progress bar:**

```
bigtext =
(
Put all your big text here
Put all your big text here
Put all your big text here
)

Progress, zh0 m2 fs10 w600, %bigtext%
return

~esc::Progress, Off
```